# how to print grand total on last page in crystalreport?

Tags: crystal-reports

the grand total has to be print on last page 
if i have  2 pages in crystal report then the grand should be print on 2 nd page not on 1st page

how should i do this please help me out

Answer (score 1):

In the Crystal Reports designer you have several places by default (report header, page header...).

To set something to appear in the last page you should use "report footer".

Answer (score 0):

[Crystal report tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227712%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

This might help. Just have a look

If you got some time look at the videos in here http://www.vtc.com/products/Crystal-Reports-XI-Beginner-Tutorials.htm